# Linked List how to add value to from an array?

Tags: javascript

I am following a linked list problem in Eloquent JavaScript book and I don't understand how the value for the first link is 10 and not 20 if i is = 1, in the first iteration of the for loop.

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  let list = null;
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    list = { value: array[i], rest: list }; //why is the value 10 and not 20 if i = 1, 
  }
  return list;
}
console.log(arrayToList([10, 20]));
```

> {value: 10, rest: {value: 20, rest: null}}

I think I am thinking of the for loop the wrong way, but I don't know where.

Comment: On the first iteration of the for loop, it does return value 20. But list has been reassigned with decremented index in the next loop giving you the value 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value **is** 20. The explanation is that the loop is running backwards, adding `list` as a value of the property `rest`. Thus, the outermost object has the first value in the array and the innermost object has the last value in the array.

Have a look at this demo, where the console shows the values for each iteration:

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  let list = null;
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(`The index is ${i} and the value is ${array[i]}`)
    list = { value: array[i], rest: list }; //why is the value 10 and not 20 if i = 1, 
  }
  return list;
}
arrayToList([10, 20]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is synchronous. It 'stops' the other part of the code and evaluates the code block inside the loop until i >= 0. This reassigns the 'value' in 'list' until i = 0 which, in turn, assigns value to 10.